# Delete dynamic generated data?

Tags: json, angularjs, sorting, dynamic

I have a problem with my delete function ! As long as I delete data which comes from my json file everything works fine. But if you will add some more data - it will delete the wrong trips or days depending wether it is older or newer(e.g. if you will enter an older date it deletes the next day or trip). 
The problem shows within both delete functions (deleteTrip and delTripDay). There must be an error with the index. Any idea ?

Furthermore I would like to export the data to json - which works good so far. If you add some data, it will put the new data to the end of my json object. I would like to add a filter to my save function to sort the new saved JSON data same way like it is displayed above !

--> descending date !

Is there any solution for sorting trips and DAYS ??

[**plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MRAhLk7NxZHx4mTLaYxt?p=preview)

The code:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('showTrips', []);


      app.controller('TripController', ['$scope', '$http',
        function($scope, $http) {
          $http.get('trips.json').success(function(data) {

            $scope.trips = data;

            $scope.addTrip = function() {
              $scope.trips.push({
                'Startdate': $scope.newtrip,
                DAYS: []
              })
              $scope.newtrip = ''
            }

            $scope.deleteTrip = function(index) {
              $scope.trips.splice(index, 1);
            }

            $scope.delTripDay = function(trip, index) {
              trip.DAYS.splice(index, 1);
            }


            $scope.savedJSON = '';

            $scope.save = function() {
              $scope.savedJSON = angular.toJson($scope.trips);
            };


          });


        }
      ]);


      app.controller("DayController", function() {

        this.day = {};
        this.addDay = function(trip) {
          trip.DAYS.push(this.day);
          this.day = {};
        }

      });

    })();
```

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the right index to the functions? Notice that when you use filters (like the orderby and filter by query), the original array (trips) stays the same. Meaning the original indices do not change. Instead of passing the index to the function, try to send the object itself. Another option is to apply the filters in the controller and not the html.

Comment: you need to put filter in your code while deleting..because the list shown on UI is filtered and the list from which you are deleting is not filtered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you were filtering array on UI using angular filter and deleting array from non-filtered array was deleting different days object.

You only need to change `deleteTripDay` function like below.

**CODE**

```
$scope.delTripDay = function(trip, index) {
    //creating array structure like UI
    var deleteDays = $filter('orderBy')($filter('filter')(trip.DAYS, $scope.query), 'DATE');
    deleteDays.splice(index, 1); // then delete by index
    trip.DAYS = deleteDays; //reassigning update array to trip days
}
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/8lhTgSl1Pka4DoP60r1D?p=preview)

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your approach ! But deleting isn't working correct ! If you add several days before and after for example to trip nr. 2 (15.02.2014) you may notice that it still deletes the wrong days.

Comment: big thanks pankajparkar ! now it is working ! I only added following code: $scope.trip.DAYS = $filter('orderBy')($filter('filter')(trip.DAYS, $scope.query), 'DATE'); what updates my array after deleting any value to the correct sort order. Once again thanks for your help.